# Pending transaction, what can i do

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, mining-pools, unconfirmed-transactions, mining-hardware

Pending transaction and it been 8 day, anyone can help me here and here 3MPTn2ZwQiydkvKZKRgAVUQawA9ShjLJVh , need help

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've used a very small fees  96.339 sat/B for this transaction.

You can see the current bitcoin fees here : https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ which is recommended. Your transaction will likely drop out of blockchain and you will get your coins back soon.

Solutions :

1) You can contact bitcoin pools and push your transaction in there blocks.

2) You can double spend your bitcoins ( Not easy for beginners/non-technical persons )

3) You can just wait it out.

Please use a higher fees from next time to avoid using these issues.

Comment: Thank you very much and how can i contact the bitcoin pools to push my transaction

Comment: You can find one online at viabtc.com